# Select all rows on a radgrid component

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, radgrid

I have a telerik radgrid component. It has paging (Pagesize 10). Its total rows are mostly about 130 - 140. How can i select all these data, including the ones whis are not on the screen at that time. For example i am at the third page. I press a button to select all and it should select all data on every page. Is that possible?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the [ask] page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 1):

Selecting all rows on all pages is impossible: http://www.telerik.com/forums/radgrid---select-all-from-all-pages
Instead disable paging and select all rows:

```
RadGrid1.AllowPaging = false;
RadGrid1.Rebind();
```

Read here for more info:
http://www.telerik.com/support/code-library/get-selected-items-through-all-pages

**EDIT:**
Perhaps you can set a `bool` inside the `ViewState` when that button is clicked; if the `bool == true` and you navigate to another page, you can reselect all those rows on that page. Also, when it is true, you can perform your logic based on that; I hope this helps. You can use the `NeedDataSource` event for this.

Comment: Yes i need something like that, but radgrid.MasterTableView.Items should include the whole data, not only on the page ones. I have paging on my radgrid, when i do something like your code, i only get 10 items, i need the whole datasource data at this loop

Comment: I tried that solution, but it does not work for me. Someone else gived this as the answer of my question, but it's not working for me, i dont know why

Comment: What does not work? In the sample you do `RadGrid1.AllowPaging = false;
RadGrid1.Rebind();` then, afterwards you re-enable paging: `RadGrid1.AllowPaging = true; RadGrid1.Rebind();` This should all occur in your event `button_Click`.

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? Selecting all rows visibly, exporting data or ...?

Comment: When i do this, i still can only reache 10 items, but my grid has 130 items. This code can only reache one page's items. Not the whole